# List not being populated using jQuery with JSON data

Tags: jquery, html, json, html-lists

I am trying to populate a ordered list with JSON using jQuery but the data is not being added to the list. I pasted my code in Fiddle and it seems to be working just as it should.

JavaScript file:

```
var data = {
    "product": [
        "Product 1",
        "Product 2",
        "Product 3"
    ],

    "company": [
        "Company 1",
        "Company 2",
        "Company 3"
    ],

    "contact": [
        "Contact 1",
        "Contact 2",
        "Contact 3"
    ]
};

$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    if (key === 'product') {
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            var option = ('<li>' + value[i] + '</li>');
            $('#product').append(option);
        }
    }
    if (key === 'company') {
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            var option = ('<li>' + value[i] + '</li>');
            $('#company').append(option);
        }
    }
    if (key === 'contact') {
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            var option = ('<li id="new">' + value[i] + '</li>');
            $('#contact').append(option);
        }
    }
});

$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
    $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    var checkElement = $(this).next();

    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }

    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }

    if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
            <ul id='product'>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a>
            <ul id='company'>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a>
            <ul id='contact'>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the code in Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9kW3X/12/

I am currently using a Mobile Ready HTML5 MVC.NET template in Visual Studio 2010.

I am using other jQuery code in my project that is working correctly so I doubt it is a source problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but you should reasearch a bit. I guess that in MVC.NET, you cannot use the traditional jQuery JSON parse (I guess you are using Ajax).

Answer (score 0):

Your json was not proper.

http://jsfiddle.net/vsah/R3dcw/9/

```
var data = {
"data":{
    "product": [
    "product1",
    "product2",
    "produc3"],
    "company": [
    "company1",
    "company2",
    "company3"]
 }
}

$.each(data, function (key, value) {

if(value.product){
    var product = '<ul data-role="listview">'
    $.each(value.product, function (key, value) {
       product += '<li>'+value+'</li>';
    });
    $("#product").append(product).trigger('create');
}

if(value.company){
    var company = '<ul data-role="listview">'
    $.each(value.company, function (key, value) {
       company += '<li>'+value+'</li>';
    });
    $("#company").append(company).trigger('create');
 }


});
```

Comment: This works in Fiddle but not in VS2010. I think it may have something to do with the HMTL page. This is what my HTML page looks like ("Index.cshtml"): http://jsfiddle.net/R3dcw/12/

Comment: As I said; it is working on Fiddle but not on VS2010.